# ¿Uso de "el cual" o "Mismo qué"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

¿En la redacción, especialmente de documentos legales se utiliza mucho, "mismo que" para sustituir "el cual", es eso correcto? Por ejemplo, "Ellos recibieron la inducción necesaria y una guía de usuario, misma que es una ayuda técnica para brindar el paso a paso de cómo ingresar al sistema"

Comment: Yo lo he visto también. Y encontré otro ejemplo: "En su carácter de el asociado; y a quienes en obsequio a la brevedad en lo sucesivo se les denominara “la asociada”; **mismo que tienen propalado** y que desean sujetar al tenor de las posteriores cláusulas, previas las siguientes" (https://www.proz.com/kudoz/spanish-to-english/law-contracts/2935801-mismo-que-tienen-propalado.html).  // ¡Aprovecho para darte la bienvenida al sitio!

Answer (score 1):

De la entrada de [mismo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=apcQb0FGPD6m7ysHSu) en el DPD (*cursivas* en el original, **negritas** mías):

> En México y el área centroamericana es frecuente, en textos periodísticos o de prosa divulgativa, emplear *mismo* (a menudo sin artículo) como antecedente del *que* relativo que introduce oraciones explicativas; es uso superfluo, **que debe evitarse, pues el solo relativo basta**: «Claro penal sobre Hugo Santana, *mismo que* transformó Caballero con tiro potente» (Excélsior [Méx.] 17.9.01); debió decirse, simplemente, "Claro penal sobre Hugo Santana, que transformó Caballero" .

Es decir, según el DPD, este uso se limita a Centroamérica y "debe evitarse". En España nunca he visto ni oído esta construcción.